# Homebrew Apache using default macOs apache conf file

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, httpd.conf

My M1 got coffee so I bought a "new" 2013 Intel MacBook Pro, I used the Apple Migration Assistant, a good idea till I started having issues with some apps designed for Apple Silicon.

My homebrew httpd is using ***/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*** instead of ***/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf***

How I know it ? By adding changes to ***/etc/apache2/httpd.conf*** and restarting sudo `/usr/local/bin/apachectl restart`

Anyone has experienced that behavior ?

When I hit localhost, it's working but when I hit on Terminal `brew services list`, I got an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by starting from the beginning after deleting from .zshrc file `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/sbin:$PATH"`

This was added from my previous installation and in some way i guess it was conflicting with new path `export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"`